Entanglement distillation algorithm with increased expected entanglement
$\newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left| #1 \right\rangle}$
Consider an entangled two-qubit state given by
$$
\ket{\psi} = \cos\theta \ket{00} + \sin\theta\ket{11},
$$
i.e., neither $\sin\theta$ nor $\cos\theta$ is zero.
Now, suppose we have two copies of this state, i.e., our total state is $\ket{\psi}^{\otimes 2}$.
Is there an entanglement distillation protocol that, using only local operations and classical communication, produces a two-qubit state such that, for any value of $\theta$, the expected entanglement entropy of the post-protocol state is at least the entanglement entropy of a single copy of $\ket{\psi}$? In other words, a protocol such that the following inequality hold:
$$
\sum_{\text{successful outcomes}} p_{\text{successful outcome}} \cdot S_{\text{outcome}} \geq S(\ket{\psi}),
$$
where $S_{\text{outcome}}$ is the entanglement entropy of the state after a successful outcome of the protocol, and $S(\ket{\psi})$ is the entanglement entropy of the initial state $\ket{\psi}$?

Does the protocol know theta classically? Also I assume you want to omit the vacuous do-nothing protocol, which has this property.

Yes, I definitely want to omit the vacuous do-nothing protocol. Ideally, I would like the protocol to work without knowing theta classically, but I would still be happy to hear about a protocol that does the job but requires knowledge of theta.

I'm not sure if what you actually want is to increase the entanglement entropy, maybe you actually want a protocol that produces a 2 qubit state with high entanglement entropy or high fidelity to the bell state or something like that?

Yes, you are right. I will edit the question to make it more clear.

I feel like you can't have that: imagine $\theta$ very close to 0 or 1. Then both states are almost separable, and therefore you should expect the probability required to distill any decent amount of entanglement to be very small. In the limit $\theta\to0$ the probability of successfully distilling any fixed target amount of entanglement should go to 0

I agree that based on your intuitive argument it seems unlikely; however, I haven't been able to prove it's not possible. Some intuition for why I think it may be possible is the following. Suppose I start off with two copies of a two-qubit state with $\epsilon$ entanglement entropy. Heuristically, shouldn't I be able to "combine" the two copies of my two-qubit state to get a different two-qubit state with more entanglement entropy that the initial two-qubit state with entanglement entropy $\epsilon$ but less than the total $2\epsilon$ entanglement entropy that I started off with?

Clearly, it is impossible to do this determinisitcally, but I was hoping that you would still at least be able to end up with more than $\epsilon$ entanglement entropy on average.
